# Image upload and edit in ASP.NET / Razor

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, razor

I am trying to do something like this:
http://i-load.radactive.com/en/demos/features/imageContraints/

I would have happily paid for this but it's been discontinued. Does anyone know of something *very* similar that I can add to my ASP.NET Razor syntax web pages (or even just an aspx page).

I've been searching high and low through google but the majority of these things only crop, I also want to rotate and zoom in and out, then save the result to the server.

Any help greatly appreciated as I cannot afford to lose anymore hair / sleep.

Thanks,
nl

Answer (score 3):

This article does something similar with jQuery and JCrop - will it fit your purposes?

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET

It's not razor, but I'm not sure if you'll find much that is since it's relatively new. Since this page is fairly isolated, that might not be an issue :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I since paid a freelancer to do this in Jquery and HTML 5 <canvas> using razor only to save the image at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://piczard.com
(it's free)

Comment: As is currently, no. It's meant for webforms.